# Bad result from DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, datediff

i have table, where i have column TIME_SEND (time(7)). Int this table i have value 09:50:00. 
This is my code:

```
select DATEDIFF(mi,GETDATE(),(select TIME_SEND from FASTREPORT_SEND))
```

I want to give difference between actual time (in minutes) and time into column TIME_SEND.

But the result is:

```
-59850741
```

Have you any idea, why it is bad?

Comment: Isn't the result a timestamp? maybe you just need to format it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the number of minutes between 09:50:00 on 1st January 1900 and right now. You comparing a `datetime` to a `time`, so the server helpfully expands the `time` to a `datetime` value so that it can compare Apples and Apples.

This query returns a more sensible result (currently 18):

```
select DATEDIFF(mi,CONVERT(time(7),GETDATE()),CONVERT(time(7),'09:50:00'))
```

Where I've used `CONVERT(time(7),'09:50:00')` in lieu of having access to your tables and data.